Moving toolbar settings in sculpt mode for smaller window
Hey does anyone know hwo to move these settings to the left, so my smaller screen can access them?


If you hover your mouse over the top bar in that window and scroll with your mousewheel then it will move to that end. Those buttons are there, they're just "Off screen"

Hover the mouse over the toolbar and drag left and right with the Middle Mouse Button:


Thank you brother this works so well!

No problem! Please mark my answer as accepted (with the green check mark) to indicate to others researching the problem that it is correct. Thanks.
